# ngStyle VS Renderer2 ? What should I use?

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-style, angular-renderer2

I'm using Angular 5.2.9.

I was wondering when should I use Renderer2 over ngStyle ? Which is the best solution ?

1:`<div #div>FOO BAR</div>`

```
  @ViewChild('div') div: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.div.nativeElement, 'background', 'blue');
  }
```

2:`<div [ngStyle]="styleValue">FOO BAR</div>`

```
  styleValue: any = {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.styleValue = {background: 'blue'};
  }
```

I know that it is easier to use "ngStyle" in a ngFor, eg:

```
<div ngFor="let elem of array" [ngStyle]="styleValue">
```

Otherwise you should do for this case: `<div ngFor="let elem of array" #div>FOO BAR</div>`

```
  @ViewChildren('div') divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.divs.change.subscribe(() => {
        this.toFlipArray.forEach((div) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.div.nativeElement, 'background', 'blue');
        })
     }
  }
```

This seems much more longer in  a ngFor to use Renderer2 and I have even not killed the subscription.

Is there a difference in performance ? Maybe somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ngStyle` and `renderer.setStyle` are used to dynamically style a component

But `renderer.setStyle` looks to take precedence over `[ngStyle]` even if `ngStyle` looks to be a type of embedded style.

Demo example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtdk4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

> When looking to the internal implementation of `ngStyle`:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts

> it looks like it itself is implemented using `renderer.setStyle`

```
@Directive({selector: '[ngStyle]'})
export class NgStyle implements DoCheck {
  private _ngStyle: {[key: string]: string};
  private _differ: KeyValueDiffer<string, string|number>;

  constructor(
      private _differs: KeyValueDiffers, private _ngEl: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @Input()
  set ngStyle(v: {[key: string]: string}) {
    this._ngStyle = v;
    if (!this._differ && v) {
      this._differ = this._differs.find(v).create();
    }
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this._differ) {
      const changes = this._differ.diff(this._ngStyle);
      if (changes) {
        this._applyChanges(changes);
      }
    }
  }

  private _applyChanges(changes: KeyValueChanges<string, string|number>): void {
    changes.forEachRemovedItem((record) => this._setStyle(record.key, null));
    changes.forEachAddedItem((record) => this._setStyle(record.key, record.currentValue));
    changes.forEachChangedItem((record) => this._setStyle(record.key, record.currentValue));
  }

  private _setStyle(nameAndUnit: string, value: string|number|null|undefined): void {
    const [name, unit] = nameAndUnit.split('.');
    value = value != null && unit ? `${value}${unit}` : value;

    if (value != null) {
      this._renderer.setStyle(this._ngEl.nativeElement, name, value as string);
    } else {
      this._renderer.removeStyle(this._ngEl.nativeElement, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: if ngStyle is using Renderer then can we assume it's also using Renderer2?

Comment: Yes,  look at what is injected in the constructor in the code: ``private _renderer: Renderer2``. you see that Renderer2 is injected.

Comment: awesome, so they are the same thing; and no worry of [ngStyle] would expose vulnerability.

Comment: [Renderer2, provides an API that can safely be used](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/top-5-best-practices-angular-app-security.aspx). With a quick search I found that link, but you can search more to find best practices for Angular App Security. So ``[ngStyle]`` should not expose vulnerability.