# How to proper update UI when a property changes in Angular 5

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I am trying to update UI automatically, avoiding jQuery. I just want to update a css of a button after a click happened.

Should it be done in html with inline javascript code or typescript component?

Right now I am evaluating the latter, handling CSS in typescript as follows.

The component which changes its `alreadyLiked` property:

```
sendLike(recipientId: number) {
  this.userService.sendLike(fromUserId, this.user.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.alertifyService.success('You have liked ' + this.user.name);

     // any way to update UI without this trash?
     const btnLikeMe = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('btnLikeMe');
     btnLikeMe.classList.remove('btn-primary');
     btnLikeMe.classList.add('btn-success');
     btnLikeMe.classList.add('active');
     btnLikeMe.disabled = true;

   }, error => {
        this.alertifyService.error(error);
   });
}
```

After `alreadyLiked` is changed, I would like to update `btnLikeMe` css automatically in HTML:

```
<button id="btnLikeMe" class="btn" (click)="sendLike(user.id)"
[disabled]="alreadyLiked"
[ngClass]="alreadyLiked ? 'btn-success active' : 'btn-primary'"
title="{{alreadyLiked?'You already liked me. Thank you' : 'Like me now!'}}">
Like
</button>
```

It is working but it seems to be a bad approach.
I am using `"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need JQuery for this. NgClass is the right way.

> NgClass adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

In some point if you want do to more complex things you can call functions...`[ngClass]="getClass()"`
Then you can debugging, but you can`t do this in HTML.
When you have to touch the DOM, you should use Renderer2.

Comment: [ngstyle-vs-renderer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193146/ngstyle-vs-renderer2-what-should-i-use)