# How to manipulate a <DIV> style in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, styles, angular8

Want to manipulate style's display. Here is the template:

```
<div style="display: none" #myDiv />
```

Thought there are 2 ways to do it:

1. directly

   `if (1===1) this.myDiv.style.display = "block";`
2. via @ViewChild

   `@ViewChild('myDiv', { static: false}) myDiv
   if (1===1) this.myDiv.style.display = "block";`

none working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) for this as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-div" style="display: none" />
```

**TS**

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  myDiv;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.myDiv = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div');
  }
}
```

Then you can change styles using `myDiv` variable as follows.

```
this.myDiv.style.display = 'block';
```

**[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-59013913?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Isn't this lots of typing for just one directive/property? Or it may has some advantage over ngStyle?

Comment: This is how you change `DOM` styles programmatically or you can use `ngClass` and change classes according to some boolean variable.

Comment: what about `ngStyle`?

Comment: `ngStyle` also fine. but it is limited no. if you use `ngClass` you can use any number of classes with few `boolean` variables

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngStyle`:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'display': flag ? 'block' : 'none'}">
    ...
</div>
```

where `flag` can correspond to any boolean variable based on your logic in the corresponding .ts file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Renderer2**](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to set style as well, The prototype of setStyle is as following:

[setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags?: RendererStyleFlags2): void](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setStyle)

**Parameters:**

```
el: any,     The element for whcih you set the style.

style:  string,  The name of the style.

value:  any,      The new value for style.

flags   RendererStyleFlags2,  Flags for style variations. No flags are set by default.
```

**So you have to avoid use of ElementRef** because direct access to the dom is not good for security, it is not safe, You can instead use Renderer2 to set Style

**Demo example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-oryw2m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Code Example:**

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.test.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'red');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.test.nativeElement, 'color', 'white');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the details, as you answered in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193146/ngstyle-vs-renderer2-what-should-i-use/50194596?noredirect=1#comment104292769_50194596), `[ngStyle]` is actually usinge `Renderer`, I'd go with the simpler `ngStyle`.